# .net Maui: How get Maui version number?

Tags: .net, version, maui

How do I know what version of Maui I'm on/using. I used the Visual Studio installer and tried checking, but I can't tell if I'm on preview 3 which I originally installed or have I managed to update to GA?

Bizarre that I can't find this information from searching. :(

Answer (score 11):

I found this information by using the dotnet command line tool:

> dotnet workload list

The results I got looked like this:

```
Installed Workload Ids      Manifest Version                              Installation Source
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
maui-android                6.0.540/6.0.400                               SDK 6.0.400, VS 17.3.32901.215
maui-tizen                  6.0.540/6.0.400                               SDK 6.0.400
maui-windows                6.0.540/6.0.400                               VS 17.3.32901.215
maui-maccatalyst            6.0.540/6.0.400                               VS 17.3.32901.215
maccatalyst                 15.4.446-ci.-release-6-0-4xx.446/6.0.400      VS 17.3.32901.215
maui-ios                    6.0.540/6.0.400                               VS 17.3.32901.215
ios                         15.4.446-ci.-release-6-0-4xx.446/6.0.400      VS 17.3.32901.215
android                     32.0.465/6.0.400                              VS 17.3.32901.215

Use `dotnet workload search` to find additional workloads to install.
```

dotnet has a multitude of options for installing and updating stuff too.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's kind of curious not having this info. I found [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-maui-rc-3/) and it mentions

> To acquire .NET MAUI RC3 on Windows, install or update Visual Studio 2022 Preview to version 17.3 Preview 1. In the installer, confirm .NET MAUI (preview) is checked under the “Mobile Development with .NET” workload.

So, I guess you need to check your VS version in order to find MAUI version too.

Comment: That is my conclusion also. I presume it wasn't worth giving it a version number until VS itself is no longer "Preview". Until then, its not independent of VS.

Comment: Okay, but how do I know if I'm on the preview version 3 or the now released GA version? And anyway how do I move to GA??? Sorry I checked Visual Studio Installer and I seem to be on 17.3.0 Preview 1.1 so does that mean I'm on GA?

Comment: If you have installed VS 17.3.0 you must have MAUI 6.0.312. According to the next link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app?pivots=devices-android. Also, check this one the release notes of this version. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/releases/tag/6.0.312. For last, this tool shows you MAUI version at the very top https://github.com/Redth/dotnet-maui-check

Comment: :) The maui-check tool shows the environment versions but not a Maui version! It has also scared the heck out of me saying stuff in the android sdk is missing.... I hesitate to allow it to fix it for me :) I'm checking via Android Studio.

Comment: At the top under the logo it is showing the version of the check tool I think, not Maui.

Comment: Well I first checked with Android Studio and updated everything I could see and then ran the maui-check tool and allowed it to fix and got a load of failures. Man why is everything so error strewn. :sigh